# Array of values as input in Snakemake workflows

Tags: python, pandas, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs, nextflow

I started to migrate my workflows from `Nextflow` to `Snakemake` and already hitting the wall at the start of my pipelines which very often begin with a list of numbers (representing a "run number" from our detector).

What I have for example is a `run-list.txt` like

```
# detector_id run_number
75 63433
75 67325
42 57584
42 57899
42 58998
```

which then needs to be passed line by line to a process that queries a database or data storage system and retrieves a file to the local system.

This means that e.g. `75 63433` would generate the output `RUN_00000075_00063433.h5` via a rule which receives `detector_id=75` and `run_number=63433` as input parameters.

With `Nextflow` this is fairly easy, just defining a process which emits a tuple of these values.

I don't quite understand how I can do something like this in `Snakemake` since it seems that inputs and outputs always needs to be files (remote or local). In fact, some of the files are indeed accessible via iRODS and/or XRootD but even then, I need to start with a run-selection first which is defined in a list like the `run-list.txt` above.

My question is now: what is the Snakemake-style approach to this problem?

A **non-working pseudo-code** would be:

```py
rule:
    input:
        [line for line in open("run-list.txt").readlines()]
    output:
        "{detector_id}_{run_number}.h5"
    shell:
        "detector_id, run_number = line.split()"
        "touch "{detector_id}_{run_number}.h5""
```

Comment: So I understand it correctly: I assume run number and detector ID need to be fed into something in the actual command? Should they be zero-padded at this point, or is that just for the output filename?

Comment: Yes exactly `:)`

Comment: Yes to which - zero-padding when used, or zero-padding only in the output? Or to the first part?

Comment: Sorry, my brain is already scrumbled. It's just for the output filename but that part is not so important. Thanks for you answer already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work you need two ingredients:

1. a rule that specifies the logic for generating a single file (defining any file dependencies, if necessary)
2. a rule that defines which file should be calculated, by convention this rule is called `all`.

Here is a rough sketch of the code:

```py
def process_lines(file_name):
    """generates id/run, ignoring non-numeric lines"""
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            detector_id, run_number, *_ = line.split()
            if detector_id.isnumeric() and run_number.isnumeric():
                detector_id = detector_id.zfill(8)
                run_number = run_number.zfill(8)
                yield detector_id, run_number


out_file_format = "{detector_id}_{run_number}.h5"
final_files = [
    out_file_format.format(detector_id=detector_id, run_number=run_number)
    for detector_id, run_number in process_lines("run-list.txt")
]


rule all:
    """Collect all outputs."""
    input:
        final_files,


rule:
    """Generate an output"""
    output:
        out_file_format,
    shell:
        """
        echo {wildcards[detector_id]}
        echo {wildcards[run_number]}
        echo {output}
        """
```

Comment: Ah ok many thanks. I think I now understood that it kind of goes "backwards". I have to read a bit more about this `wildcard` thing though, seems a bit magical ;)

Answer (score 3):

In Snakemake you'd use this file to generate lists of the values you want to feed into your workflow. You'd parse the detector IDs and run numbers outside the rules. Off the top of my head your run list looks like it could neatly be handled with pandas, if you want to use an external library.

```py
import pandas as pd

run_list = pd.read_csv("run-list.txt", header=0, names=["detector_id", "run_number"], sep=" ")
detector_ids = list(run_list["detector_id"])
run_numbers = list(run_list["run_number"])
```

Then a rule for running what you want to do for getting *one* file would be, under the assumption your file names do *not* need to be zero-padded:

```py
rule do_something:
    output: "{detector_id}_{run_number}.h5"
    shell: "do_something_with {wildcards.detector_id} {wildcards.run_number}"
```

With just this rule alone, `detector_id` and `run_number` could in theory be anything, so you'll need something to tell Snakemake to run this in a way that produces the output you want. To run this for *all* lines in your file, you'd therefore set up a rule that takes all potential outputs defined by the file as input.

```py
rule run_all:
    input: expand("{detector_id}_{run_number}.h5", zip, detector_id=detector_ids, run_number=run_numbers)
```

with the `zip` part ensuring that the first detector ID goes with the first run number and so on.

Finally, you'd run it specifying the name of the rule you want to run, so `snakemake run_all`.

Answer (score 2):

Already some good answers but since I got the code in the meantime here's my 2p. Save as `Snakefile` and it should be runnable.

```
import pandas

# In reality you read this from file using pandas.read_csv.
# Or use a solution other than pandas dataframes.
run_list = [(75, 63433),
(75, 67325),
(42, 57584),
(42, 57899),
(42, 58998)]

run_list = pandas.DataFrame(run_list, columns= ['detector_id', 'run_id'])

rule all:
    input:
        expand('RUN_{detector_id}_{run_id}.h5', zip, detector_id= run_list.detector_id, run_id= run_list.run_id),

rule make_run:
    output:
        'RUN_{detector_id}_{run_id}.h5',
    shell:
        r"""
        touch {output}
        """
```

You would need some string manipulation for the zero-padding but that is a python thing, not snakemake's.