# Snakemake is unable to match wildcard although it's defined and even suggested

Tags: snakemake

I am still very confused about the wildcards concept despite reading the full docs and a few examples, so maybe someone can shed light on this weird behaviour. It might be a bug but it's such a basic example that I am pretty sure I am doing or understanding something wrong.

Here is my `Snakefile` which should generate a bunch of files defined in a dictionary where the location of the files is stored (those can be served by all kinds of data providers like iRODS, XRootD etc., but it's not important now).

```py
import os

some_files = {
    "foo": "some_location/foo",
    "bar": "another_location/bar",
    "baz": "yet_another_loc/baz"
}

rule all:
    input: ["raw/" + os.path.basename(f) for f in some_files.keys()]

rule generate_files:
    output:
        temp("raw/{fname}")
    shell:
        "echo grabbed file from {some_files[wildcards.fname]} > {output}"
```

As you can see, I need to use a similar "trick" which was proposed in my previous question ([Array of values as input in Snakemake workflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71142612/array-of-values-as-input-in-snakemake-workflows)) to force the recognition of the files by adding a rule and listing those (in `rule all`), which works nicely.

The `rule generate_files` should then generate (retrieve) those by using the corresponding URL and protocol defined in `some_files`. For the sake of simplicity, it's now just echoing the origin into the `output` file.

To achieve this, I thought I can simply use the `wildcards.fname` in the `shell` section but I when I run the workflow, I get:

```
░ tamasgal@silentbox-(2):PhD/snakemake  master ●●● snakemake took 16s
░ 08:47:35 > snakemake -c1
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job               count    min threads    max threads
--------------  -------  -------------  -------------
all                   1              1              1
generate_files        3              1              1
total                 4              1              1

Select jobs to execute...

[Fri Feb 18 08:47:38 2022]
rule generate_files:
    output: raw/bar
    jobid: 2
    wildcards: fname=bar
    resources: tmpdir=/var/folders/84/mcvklq757tq1nfrkbxvvbq8m0000gn/T

RuleException in line 12 of /Users/tamasgal/Dev/PhD/snakemake/Snakefile:
NameError: The name 'wildcards.fname' is unknown in this context. Please make sure that you defined that variable. Also note that braces not used for variable access have to be escaped by repeating them, i.e. {{print $1}}
```

If I use `fname` (and not `wildcards.fname`), `Snakemake` proposes to use `wildcards.fname`, which again, does not work. Here is the output when running with `fname` in `output`:

```
[Fri Feb 18 08:47:48 2022]
rule generate_files:
    output: raw/bar
    jobid: 2
    wildcards: fname=bar
    resources: tmpdir=/var/folders/84/mcvklq757tq1nfrkbxvvbq8m0000gn/T

RuleException in line 12 of /Users/tamasgal/Dev/PhD/snakemake/Snakefile:
NameError: The name 'fname' is unknown in this context. Did you mean 'wildcards.fname'?
```

Why is this happening? The output of the workflow clearly shows that `wildcards: fname=bar`, so it exists and is defined. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, you may have to try and get at `some_files[wildcards.fname]` outside of the `shell` part? It looks to me like it can tell what the wildcard is supposed to be for the output to be `raw/bar`, but it can't handle using it to access the dict in the `shell` part. It seems like this could be handled with an [input function](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/advanced.html#tutorial-input-functions) to me.

Off the top of my head:

```py
rule generate_files:
    input:
        some_file = lambda wildcards: some_files[wildcards.fname]
    output:
        temp("raw/{fname}")
    shell:
        "echo grabbed file from {input.some_file} > {output}"
```

EDIT: if it fails because the file isn't local so Snakemake can't find it, you may supply the path to it as a parameter instead:

```py
rule generate_files:
    params:
        some_file = lambda wildcards: some_files[wildcards.fname]
    output:
        temp("raw/{fname}")
    shell:
        "echo grabbed file from {params.some_file} > {output}"
```

Comment: Hm, the problem is that `some_file` is not an actual file location on the local filesystem, so I guess the workflow will fail since it assumes that those paths exist. In the real scenario, the dictionary contains a path on a remote server or data provider.

Comment: All right, there's a workaround for that too, I'll edit that in

Comment: I also tried calling a Python function inside the `{}` to look up the URL for a `fname` but that has failed with the same error (`wildcards.fname` not defined), so I guess `{}` is truly reserved for variables and formatters and is not a real Python context.

Comment: Ah yeah, `params`, I just found it at the same time ;D many thanks KeyboardCat!